# Data is not being passed from ajax to controller

Tags: ajax, firebase-authentication, controller, google-signin, cakephp-4.x

I`m trying to make google authentication. In add.php(templates file) I wrote this javascript code .

```
function singIn() {//<------this is called when button is pressed

firebase.auth()
            .signInWithPopup(provider)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                var credential = result.credential;

                // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
                var token = credential.accessToken;

                // The signed-in user info.
                var user = result.user;

                var userInfo = JSON.stringify(user); //to Post
$.ajax({
method: “POST”,
url: “<?= Router::url(array('controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'googlesignin')); ?>”,
data: {
userInfo
},
success: function(data) {
console.log(“Signed in google!”);
},

                error: function(param) {
                    console.log("Something went wrong" + param.responseText.message);
                    console.log("-----------------------");
                    console.log(param);
                }
            });
```

I am getting google pop and everything is working with out any errors but data is not getting passed to controller. My controller

```
public function googlesignin(){

    echo $_POST['data']['email'];
    die;
}
```

I also added this

```
$builder->connect(’/’, array(‘controller’ => ‘Users’, ‘action’ => ‘googlesignin’));
```

in routes.php.

Can someone tell me where is the problem?

Comment: This is cakephp-4

Comment: First things first, with CakePHP you should never access the superglobals directly, you should always use the abstracted APIs that CakePHP provides! In this case that would be the request object. That being said, start with inspecting the AJAX request in your browser's network console, what exactly does the payload look like, and what headers are being sent (you are manually encoding the data as JSON, and then pass it to an object, that will not turn out the way you think it will)? Also note that there will be no `data` key in the POST data, `data` is just the option name that jQuery uses.

Answer (score 0):

in Ajax

```
$.ajax({
  // ...
  headers: {
    "Accept":"application/json"
  }
  //...
```

And in your controller

```
public function googlesignin(){

   $post = $this->request->getData(); // All post data available here
   // pr($post); // print all data
   echo $post['data']['email'];
   die;
}
```